# Definition of Replete ideal of algebraic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm studying Neukirch, Algebraic number theory p.185.

Let's see the next image :

[image]

[image]

I can't understand the underlined defitnion.
What is $e$?

Comment: Its the Euler's number. But you can choose any positive real number.

Comment: Yes. O.k I also guessed so. Thank you